# How to pass authorization parameters?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I try to use framework that was created by swagger-codegen but I don't understand how to pass authorization token to my API methods.

E.g. we can use sample Petstore: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/client/petstore/android/httpclient/docs/UserApi.md#updateUser

How can I add authorisation token to my request header (that token I will receive from my previous request to AuthorizationAPI)?

Maybe I don't understand authorisation flow for swagger-codegen for Android.

```
UserApi apiInstance = new UserApi();
User body = new User(); // User | Created user object
try {
    apiInstance.createUser(body); // here I will receive error unauhorized
} catch (ApiException e) {
    System.err.println("Exception when calling UserApi#createUser");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By briefly looking at the code it looks like you can pass arbitrary http headers by invoking `addHeader`on UserApi https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/client/petstore/android/httpclient/src/main/java/io/swagger/client/api/UserApi.java#L36

Also it looks like swagger-codegen cli has support for generating the authorization headers

```
    -a <authorization>, --auth <authorization>
        adds authorization headers when fetching the swagger definitions
        remotely. Pass in a URL-encoded string of name:header with a comma
        separating multiple values
```